# How to Decode a xml Sent over Url in java

Tags: java, xml

I am firing an online xml in java to the method below:

```
 public String WriteToServer(String xml) {
     StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
     try {
         String myurl="example.com";

         URL url = new URL(myurl); 
         URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);

         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

         writer.write(xml);
         writer.flush();

         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
         String line;
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             answer.append(line);
         }

         writer.close();
         reader.close();

     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
     }
     return answer.toString();
 }
```

My Problem is that the server receives an encoded xml so it can not understand and returns a 500 response to the client. How can I decode a xml to a plain text that the server can read?

Comment: what kind of server is it ? Your own implementation ? Does it use http for communication ?

Comment: No am doing system integration. The server uses a Ip Address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code just before creating OutputStreamWriter instance

```
String myurl="example.com";
URL url = new URL(myurl); 
URLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
conn.setUseCaches (false);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```